# Accessing Alpine store externally, typescript error

Tags: javascript, typescript, alpine.js

I've set up an Alpine store like so,

```
Alpine.store( 'state', ({
  qr: ''
}))
```

And I'm trying to set it externally like so,

```
Alpine.store( 'state' ).qr = 'test'
```

But I'm getting the follow error on the qr variable from typescript,

```
any
Property 'qr' does not exist on type 'XData'.
Property 'qr' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

How can I update or access the store values without hitting these errors?

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is the following:

```
Alpine.store('state', {
    init() {
        this.qr = '';
    },
    setQr(string) {
        this.qr = string;
    },
    getQr() {
        return this.qr;
    }
});
```

And then call the setter:

```
Alpine.store( 'state' ).setQr('test');
```